# How to make up a macros to have a effect on all following text without specified?

Tags: macros

Some macros from TeX or LaTex have global effect, "`\bfseries`", "`\color{red}`", for example. This kind of macros  need not to specify the contents, because all the text followed them are affected.

I want to make up such a macro of my own. For example, the LaTex macro `\underline` must specify the texts that are underlined(i.e. `\underline{underlined contents}`). 
But I want to make up a macro, for example `\myunderline`, by which all text following it will be underlined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myunderline}{%
...
}

\begin{document}
\myunderline
% From now on, all texts are underlined
% When needed, {\myunderline some underlined text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is generally hard and not possible in full generality without rewriting most of latex. `\bfseries` _never_ access the content that is made bold, it is just a declaration that acts at that point and changes the current font. Similarly `\color`.

Comment: for the specific case of underline look at the `soul` package which underlines via a different mechanism.

Comment: Underlining in LaTeX is not easy to do in a line breakable manner. There are the `ulem` and the `soul` package for that. At least for `ulem` I did not manage to create a switch like macro so far (I could start collecting everything up until `\end{document}` and parse it, but that is very risky, most likely breaks stuff)

Comment: Yes, make a macro acting like a switch is just what I want, \myunderline is a example to illustrate my idea

Comment: @lyl you can't "make a macro act like a switch", as I explained. You can make a macro use a font change or increment a counter or do other things that do not require grabbing the rest of the text, but it is not really possible to grab the text as a macro argument.